# Subclasses and get_shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, subclass, shared-ptr

I need to find a solution to allow a subclass to get its proper smart pointer.

```
class Parent : public enable_shared_from_this {
  ...
}

class Child : public Parent {
  public Child(){
    boost::shared_ptr<Parent> pointer=shared_from_this(); // should work
    boost::shared_ptr<Child> pointer=shared_from_this(); // won't work.

  ...
}
```

How do I get the right smart pointer using shared_from_this()?

CONTEXT:

I'm writing a bit of notifier/listener stuff, and some classes will naturally need to register and unregister themselves from the notifier. For example,

```
class Body : extends Listener<BodyMessage>{ // listen for BodyMessage messages
  public:
    Body() {
      Notifier<BodyMessage>::register(this); // register with the appropriate notifier
    }

    virtual ~Body {
      Notifier<BodyMessage>::unregister(this); // unregister
    }

    bool notify(BodyMessage m){ ... }

  ...
}
```

Normally I would just use the *this* pointer, and all would be well. I've gotten the Notifier to use templates, so I can pass messages only to the ones that want to hear them.

However, I want to use smart pointers. If the notifier looks like this:

```
template<typename t>
class Notifier {
  public:
    static void register<boost::shared_ptr<Listener<t>>> boost::shared_ptr<Listener<t>> listener);

  ...
}
```

then I cannot use the *this* pointer any more. Naturally, I made Body extend enable_shared_from_this:

```
class Body : public boost::enable_shared_from_this, public Listener<BodyMessage> {
  public:
    Notifier<BodyMessage>::register(get_shared_ptr());
  ...
}
```

And that seems to works for Bodies. It doesn't work, however, for *subclasses* of bodies (or, at least, it doesn't seem to):

```
class BodyChild : public Body {
  public:
    BodyChild(){
      Notifier<BodyMessage>::register(get_shared_ptr());
}
```

likely because I can't cast a shared_pointer. SO, can I make a solution that

- lets me use shared pointers for the listeners (since these listeners are also used in other smart pointer contexts),
- lets me template the Notifier and the listeners, using the message type itself for the template, so it's super easy to listen for the specific messages and so I don't have to decode a message, and
- is simple?

I'm open to other ideas, but if I can get this to work, I'll be thrilled.

Comment: Funny, I ran against this very issue today. Using smart pointers for the Observer pattern turned out to be a very good idea. You can also use `boost::signals` to get half the work done automatically (especially with `scoped_connection` objects).

Comment: Why do you need/want `std::shared_ptr` for your notifier/listener system? Should the listeners actually be owned by the notifiers, so that they are destructed once all notifiers are gone? Or are there actually other objects, which own the listening objects and can take care of instantiation and construction? When building such a system, I have found it quite helpfull to actually keep a lot of control and not give it away.

Comment: @LiKao: One way to write the observer pattern is indeed to have the listeners keep the notifiers alive, and unsuscribe on destruction (shared_ptr + boost::signals is excellent to write this in < 50 LOC). To the contrary, I found that sticking to something very simple and rigid in this situation helps in writing better code (read: more maintainable).

Comment: @AlexandreC.: The "unsubscribe on destruction" is unclear here. If you have (mutually) owning notifiers, there never can be any "unsubscribe on destruction". As long as notifiers are available the destructor will not be called and when the destructor is called all notifiers have to be gone. So in what case will this ever happen?

Comment: @LiKao: You should strive to avoid mutual dependencies anyway. The Observer pattern has to be worked around in the presence of cycles, since objects cannot notify each other cyclically (infinite recursion). With this caveat in mind, you have to design to avoid those circular dependencies, and this is what I mean in my previous comment: the code is more maintainable if you keep it simple. If you need something more complex, then you should think about it twice (and use a completely different approach: garbage collection or robust message passing are options).

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Sure. I totally agree. This should be kept simple. Wether with or withoud `std::shared_ptr` is more simple is a different point. However my question still remains, in the light of this design, how can anything ever unsubscribe on destruction?

Comment: @Likao: The notifier only keeps privately a `boost::signal<void()>` (triggered during the `notify` method), on which the listeners connect via the `register` method. In the listener, you keep a collection of shared pointers to the notifiers, along with a `boost::signals::scoped_connection`.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Ah, there is my confusion comming from. Misread it above as "the notifiers keep the listeners alive" and not vice versa as posted. I should stop being on-line and go to bed now.

Comment: @LiKao Internally, I'm going to store the listeners as weak pointers. This way, if the listener is deleted somewhere else, the notify function can automagically unregister expired pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* cast smart pointers, and Boost provides you with a few templates to ease this. You have eg. `static_pointer_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` which allow you to cast "through" the pointer.

Since `this` is of the right dynamic type, you can invoke `boost::static_pointer_cast` on the return value of `shared_from_this()`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Child> p = static_pointer_cast<Child>(shared_from_this());
```

(no need to qualify `static_pointer_cast` thanks to Koenig lookup)

Comment: static_pointer_cast<Child>(...) is probably the best way to go in this case; thanks. Of course, I'm realizing that I probably cannot have both smart pointers used by the notifier and have objects add themselves on construction, because an object's smart pointer is not "available" until the constructors have finished.